# CSS Parent menu stay on highlighted when mouse hover to sub menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I wanted to let my "Kuantan" menu to stay highlighted after i hover to their child menu which is "kiosk no.35". But i try to change few way to let it stay active but i had failed to do so. Anything i miss out on my code? Please point my wrong. Thanks

Here is the html code:

```
<ul class="treeview-menu">
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#sub1"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Kuantan</a>
        <ul class="nav dropdown-menu" style="width:100px;height:30px">
            <li><a href="chooseOption.php?kiosk=35" style="margin-left:-20px;margin-top:-13px;" >Kiosk No.35</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> UTC Kuantan</a>
      <ul class="nav dropdown-menu" style="width:100px;height:30px">
        <li><a href="chooseOption.php?kiosk=36" style="margin-left:-20px;margin-top:-13px;" >Kiosk No.36</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Temerloh</a>
      <ul class="nav dropdown-menu" style="width:100px;height:30px">
         <li><a href="chooseOption.php?kiosk=37" style="margin-left:-20px;margin-top:-13px;" >Kiosk No.37</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Bentong</a>
    <ul class="nav dropdown-menu" style="width:100px;height:30px">
       <li><a href="chooseOption.php?kiosk=6" style="margin-left:-20px;margin-top:-13px;" >Kiosk No.6</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<hr/>
</ul>
```

Here is the css where i hover the dropdown then the dropdown-menu will came out:

```
/*3rd level sidebar menu */

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
    left:220px;
    top:0;
}
```

What i want is that after i hover the dropdown and went to dropdown-menu, the dropdwn will stay highlighted. Is there possible? Sorry i'm still new to this css skill.

Comment: if you're okay using javascript then this would be pretty simple, I believe

Comment: how it can be done with javascript? by using jquery or?

Comment: jQuery is easiest, some prefer pure javascript and it's doable with that as well.  My answer is below, of course you'll need to adjust to your preferences.

Comment: .dropdown should still be "highlighted" on :hover, because .dropdown-menu is nested inside it and therefore you are still hovering over .dropdown. You shouldn't need any JavaScript for this. Maybe add some more code or a fiddle that demonstrates what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: ... also: you can't have <hr/> as a child of <ul>, only <li> is allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in my comment - `.dropdown` should still be "highlighted" on `:hover`, because `.dropdown-menu` is nested inside it and therefore you are still hovering over `.dropdown`.

```
/* Assuming you are making nested lists display:none */
ul{
    list-style: none;
}
.dropdown-menu{
    display: none;
}
.dropdown:hover{
    background: yellow;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
    left:220px;
    top:0;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Jayx/5fh78jgj/)**

Comment: Oh, Thanks this is much simple :)

Comment: But may i know where to change the hover color ? because it seem to be only grey color on my template. I coul'nt find anywhere it located and change it. I get this template from AdminLte where i'm trying to edit the page.

Here is my css full code : http://jsfiddle.net/duqhm7wf/

Comment: Without all the markup the CSS doesn't do me much good, maybe there are other stylesheets linked to this document? Open the offending page in your browser, right click on the element that you want to inspect and hover over the list item that triggers the dropdown - you'll see which styles are applied in which stylesheet, etc.

Comment: but i can't inspect the element wheneven i try to right click the hover menu /.\

Comment: But you can right click on the parent and navigate your way through the HTML until you selected the correct element.

Answer (score 0):

By using jQuery this is one option with your current code (fiddle here:  https://jsfiddle.net/j0wLj6z9/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.dropdown').hover(function(){
     $(this).toggleClass('highlighted');
  });
  });
</script>
```

and your css is whatever you'd like:

```
.highlighted
{ 
   background: yellow;
}
```

Also include jQuery in your project:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi, i had try to apply your code, but why it still not highlighted as yellow on my page ? is there anything i have to change?

Comment: You'll need to include jQuery in your head tags <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: did you mind to have a look on my full code? because i'm trying to modify from a template, but seem like the code u provide is working on the jfiddle but not on my code. I think there is somewhere i did miss out to share it here

Comment: I don't see the need for js if all you are doing is highlighting the hovered li.  Seems like a bit of overkill (especially including a whole library for it): http://jsfiddle.net/2fxy2pmv/